# VS Code - Disabling Metrics/ClassLength not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, rubocop

I am using VS Code (latest version), using the `ruby-robocop` extension, and connected to GitHub Codespaces. In my `.github/linters/rubocop.yml` file, I have the following:

```
Metrics/ClassLength:
  Description: 'Avoid classes longer than 200 lines of code.'
  Enabled: false
```

I have this turned on for my User, Remote, and Workspace options (within the configuration). I am also pointing to this file within the ruby-robocop settings. However, when I reload VS code, it still underlines every line in my Ruby file, complaining about this cop.

When I run the `bundle exec rubocop -c .github/linters/rubocop.yml`, I don't see the `Metrics/ClassLength` error, so it's being obeyed when I run it via CLI, but not from within VS Code.

Is there another way to disable this cop using VS Code?

Comment: you're using this? https://github.com/rubocop/vscode-rubocop or what?

Comment: Didn't realize there were multiple versions of this. I'm using this: https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop. The extension in VS Code is specifically called "ruby-rubocop"

Comment: have you set the `ruby.rubocop.configFilePath` to the path to your rubocop.yml file? if not, try that and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yep. The config setting is pointing to the configuration file, but unfortunately it's not taking effect..